# Are a `GLfloat` and a `cl_float` guaranteed to have the same size?

Tags: opengl, floating-point, opencl, sizeof

After allocating a VBO using OpenGL I create an OpenCL buffer from it using [`clCreateFromGLBuffer`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLBuffer.html).

I use the VBO as an array of `GLfloat` and the OpenCL buffer as an array of `cl_float`. It works perfectly on my machine. Indeed, `GLfloat` and `cl_float` (and `float`) have the same size.

I am wondering if this would work anywhere flawlessly. In other words, is `sizeof(GLfloat) == sizeof(cl_float)` always true?<sup>*</sup> And if not, how does one usually deal with this?

<sup>* and is there documentation proving this</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you check out the CL and GL headers, you get:

```
typedef float cl_float;          // @cl_platform.h
typedef float GLfloat;           // @gl.h
```

Note in some GL implementations you get intermediary typedef's like `khronos_float_t` but ultimately it all boils down to the `float` type. So both types are identical to your native float type. Furthermore, the equivalent data types in [OpenCL kernels](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) and [OpenGL shaders](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_precision.txt) are both guaranteed to be IEEE754-conformant.

Links to relevant headers: [cl_platform.h](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl_platform.h), and the GL header depends on where you got it (they are slightly different from OS to OS and from vendor to vendor), have a look at yours. Examples: [gl.h](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/1.1/gl.h) (GLES version), [gl.h](ftp://download.nvidia.com/freebsd/71.86.13/README/gl.h) (FreeBSD nVidia version), [gl.h](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/include/GL/gl.h) (some random version).

Comment: Which `gl.h` did you pull that from?

Comment: @NicolBolas good point I was looking at the wrong header, I will edit.

Comment: @NicolBolas added some links.